# Android layout doesn´t resize when keyboard shows

Tags: android, xml, layout

as title says, i have a problem resizing my layout when keyboard appears, I did the same in new project and it works, nope in this project:

- I have added "android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in my activity manifest file
- This is my .xml file:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/contentRegister1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

  <include
  android:id="@+id/customActionBar"
  layout="@layout/action_bar_text"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

  <ScrollView
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/customActionBar">

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tvInfoRegister"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
          android:text="@string/register_header_text"
          android:textAlignment="center"
          android:textColor="#ff999999"
          android:textSize="13sp"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
          android:id="@+id/nifRegisterBox"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
          android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
          app:boxStrokeColor="@android:color/black"
          app:errorEnabled="true"
          app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextFormStyle"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvInfoRegister">

          <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
              android:id="@+id/nifRegisterValue"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:hint="@string/nif_nie"
              android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
              android:maxLength="9"
              android:maxLines="1"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="15sp" />

      </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ivOkNifRegister"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_tick"
          android:visibility="invisible"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/nifRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/nifRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/nifRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39" />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ivWrongNifRegister"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_error"
          android:visibility="invisible"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/nifRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/nifRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/nifRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39" />

      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
          android:id="@+id/birthRegisterBox"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
          android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
          app:boxStrokeColor="@android:color/black"
          app:errorEnabled="true"
          app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextFormStyle"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nifRegisterBox">

          <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
              android:id="@+id/birthRegisterValue"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:clickable="true"
              android:focusable="false"
              android:hint="@string/register_birthdate_label"
              android:inputType="date"
              android:maxLines="1"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="15sp" />

      </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ivOkBirthRegister"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_tick"
          android:visibility="invisible"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/birthRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/birthRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/birthRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39" />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ivWrongBirthRegister"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_error"
          android:visibility="invisible"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/birthRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/birthRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/birthRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39" />

      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
          android:id="@+id/mailRegisterBox"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
          android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
          app:boxStrokeColor="@android:color/black"
          app:errorEnabled="true"
          app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextFormStyle"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/birthRegisterBox">

          <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
              android:id="@+id/mailRegisterValue"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:hint="@string/register_email_label"
              android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
              android:maxLines="1"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="15sp" />

      </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ivOkMailRegister"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_tick"
          android:visibility="invisible"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/mailRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/mailRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/mailRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39" />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ivWrongMailRegister"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_error"
          android:visibility="invisible"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/mailRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/mailRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/mailRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39" />

      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
          android:id="@+id/remailRegisterBox"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
          android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
          app:boxStrokeColor="@android:color/black"
          app:errorEnabled="true"
          app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextFormStyle"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mailRegisterBox">

          <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
              android:id="@+id/remailRegisterValue"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:hint="@string/register_email_confirm_label"
              android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
              android:maxLines="1"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="15sp" />
      </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ivOkReMailRegister"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_tick"
          android:visibility="invisible"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/remailRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/remailRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/remailRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39" />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ivWrongReMailRegister"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_error"
          android:visibility="invisible"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/remailRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/remailRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/remailRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39" />

      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
          android:id="@+id/mobileRegisterBox"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
          android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
          app:boxStrokeColor="@android:color/black"
          app:errorEnabled="true"
          app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextFormStyle"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/remailRegisterBox">

          <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
              android:id="@+id/mobileRegisterValue"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:hint="@string/register_mobile_phone_label"
              android:inputType="number"
              android:maxLength="9"
              android:maxLines="1"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="15sp" />

      </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ivOkMobileRegister"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_tick"
          android:visibility="invisible"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/mobileRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/mobileRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/mobileRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39" />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ivWrongMobileRegister"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_error"
          android:visibility="invisible"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/mobileRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/mobileRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/mobileRegisterBox"
          app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39" />

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/check_box_and_text"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
          android:clickable="true"
          android:focusable="true"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mobileRegisterBox">

          <CheckBox
              android:id="@+id/legales"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
              android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector" />

          <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
              android:text="@string/register_legales_label"
              android:textSize="13sp" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/termsOfAgreement"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/register_legales_label_hiperlink"
              android:textColor="#ffd87920"
              android:textSize="13sp" />

      </LinearLayout>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tvErrorLegal"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
          android:text="@string/condiciones_legales_error"
          android:textColor="#ff0000"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:visibility="gone"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/check_box_and_text" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/btNextRegister1"
          style="@style/LoginButtonEntrarStyle"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
          android:background="@drawable/button_main_card_dashboard"
          android:text="@string/request_reset_password_init_button_next"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvErrorLegal" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  ```

And this is the include file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@drawable/dashboard_title_bg">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actionBarCentralTextView"
    style="@style/MainTitleActionBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btActionBarMenuText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/back_container_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btActionBarNotificationsText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSecondTitleText"
        style="@style/SecondaryTitleActionBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Anyone knows why it is not resizing?
Thanks,

Comment: because it dosen't have scrollview.

Comment: Edited, it has but for any reason StackOverFlow omitted it.

Answer (score 1):

By it's standard documentation:

> Boolean internal attribute to adjust view layout based on system windows such as the status bar. If true, adjusts the padding of this view to leave space for the system windows.

I think your problem would be solved by adding `android:fitsSystemWindows=true` to your root view.

Comment: Tried, but it doesn´t change anything.